# Specifying Range of Columns in Python

Tags: python, arrays, database, set, range

Specifically, I am asking how one would take several columns from a text file and input those into an array without specifying each column individually.

```
1    2   1    4.151E-12 4.553E-12 4.600E-12 4.852E-12 6.173E-12 7.756E-12 9.383E-12 1.096E-11 1.243E-11 1.379E-11 1.504E-11 1.619E-11 1.724E-11 2.139E-11 2.426E-11 2.791E-11 3.009E-11 3.152E-11 3.252E-11 3.326E-11 3.382E-11 3.426E-11 3.462E-11 3.572E-11 3.640E-11 3.698E-11 3.752E-11
2    3   1    1.433E-12 1.655E-12 1.907E-12 2.014E-12 2.282E-12 2.682E-12 3.159E-12 3.685E-12 4.246E-12 4.833E-12 5.440E-12 6.059E-12 6.688E-12 9.845E-12 1.285E-11 1.810E-11 2.238E-11 2.590E-11 2.886E-11 3.139E-11 3.359E-11 3.552E-11 3.724E-11 4.375E-11 4.832E-11 5.192E-11 5.486E-11
```

For example, I want the second column of this data set in an array by itself, and I want the third column in an array by itself. However, I want column four through the last column in arrays that are separated by column. I don't know how to do this without specifying each individual column.

Comment: No doubt there is a module which will do this for you, e.g. the pandas package can do it I think. If you want to write it yourself: read the file from disk, this will give you the data by rows, now transform these rows into columns, it is easy.

Comment: If it's all numeric data, you could have a look at `data = numpy.genfromtxt(file, unpack=True); second=data[1]; third=data[2]; fourtoend=data[3:]`. Not sure whether there's a similiar function in Python's standard library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you mentioned a text file, I'm gonna treat it as the content is fetched from a text file line by line:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()

        # I want the second column of this data set in an array by itself
        second_column = data[1]

        # I want the third column in an array by itself
        third_column = data[2]

        # I want column four through the last column in arrays that are separated by column
        fourth_to_last_column = data[3:]
```

If you then print `second_column`, `third_column` and `fourth_to_last_column` of the first line/input, it would look like this:

```
2
1
['4.151E-12', '4.553E-12', '4.600E-12', '4.852E-12', '6.173E-12', '7.756E-12', '9.383E-12', '1.096E-11', '1.243E-11', '1.379E-11', '1.504E-11', '1.619E-11', '1.724E-11', '2.139E-11', '2.426E-11', '2.791E-11', '3.009E-11', '3.152E-11', '3.252E-11', '3.326E-11', '3.382E-11', '3.426E-11', '3.462E-11', '3.572E-11', '3.640E-11', '3.698E-11', '3.752E-11']
```